# Execute python scripts on designated network interface

Tags: python, ubuntu, networking, websocket, debian

My Ubuntu VPS has two network interfaces, both public IPv4.

[image: ip addr]

This is a sample Python script I would like to run on each of the IPs.

```
# websocket.py
# websocket-client package: https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client
import websocket
import _thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    _thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_open=on_open,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close)

    ws.run_forever()
```

Is there a way to achieve this on the shell? Maybe an option to specify network interfaces?
If not, what is the common way to do this?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: You can't directly connect to a network interface in an application-level session but you can have them set up to route different addresses and then connect to an address managed by only the interface you want.

Comment: @tripleee noted, will avoid sending text data in screenshots